# How to add line at the top of keyboard in ios?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield

I have a view in which I show Numeric Keyboard. My problem is that the keyboard is missing a top line. With a white background an unpleasant effect appears:

[image]

How can I add a 1pt view at the top to simulate top line?

Comment: Is this a custom keyboard or the standard phone pad keyboard type?

Comment: This is standard keyboard in simple app, @rmaddy. I have the same issue in my main app (I only use code for moving entire view so the edited control is not hidden).

Comment: Show some relevant code in your question.

Comment: 10x, @rmaddy. Accepted answer works fine for me.

Comment: If you need code like that then something else is wrong.

Comment: I don't know @rmandy. To be sure that the problem is not in my code I created new App only with one text field. I check and I see that the upper section of the Numpad keyboard is missing border.
I have this type of keyboard before but in that case my background had colour different from white. I suppose that this is the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UIView *separatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds), 1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)];
    separatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    textField.inputAccessoryView = separatorView;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It works, except that I have to set it on `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, not on `textFieldShouldBeginEditing `.

Comment: May be, because I have code to move view (so the edited `UITextFiled` is not hidden). Also my text field is custom control.

Comment: I added the line in the viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add a 1pt tall `UIView` as the [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView) to a `UITextField`.  See [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html).

If you are using more than one field or would rather have more control over it, you can add a subview to your current controller's `view` and position it appropriately.  To do that you use the keyboard notifications posted by the OS (`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`), as described in [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present).

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3, iOS 10**

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  var separatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 1.0/UIScreen.main.scale))
  separatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
  textField.inputAccessoryView = separatorView
  return true
}
```